# Authentication system for angular (Enterprise site without login page)

Tags: angular, token

Hey we build a enterprise website for company.

When some user in the company connect to the site he have a user id.

When the id send from the client to the backend (Node.JS) I check if this id is on my Network and if he is he get a access token.

The problem is that after he get the access token  the user in the client need to reload the page again for get the access and if he not refresh the page the "Auth-Guard" block him.

What is the best practice to handle system like that in the client??

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of ways around this.

1st If you don't want the service to reply with the token on the fly, then you can go with some kind of server push technology (SignalR is the .Net solution, I'm sure there is an equivalent in node js).

2nd Why don't you send the token as a reply when the client sends the id? When you get it, keep it in a service and cache it locally. Then, when the guard is executed, get the latest value from the service and perform the validation.

Please provide more information on this.

My recommendation, would be to use some known and verified authentication method like oauth 2 or openid connect to get the token from your identity provider.

Before doing anything else, I would advise you to check [implicit grand method for oauth2](https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/spa-api/part-1), which is the reccomended way to go with Single Page Application authentication.

#### Other security concerns

- Beware that if the client id is guessable, then people can impersonate others, thus rendering your spa insecure.
- Check this [angular with ldap authentication](https://auth0.com/authenticate/angular2/ldap/). Active directory is usually the best way to go with authentication enterprise users as it is no based on client side code which is easy to bypass.

Answer (score 0):

Add [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) in the project with logic to check for the token(from cookie or local-storage wherever you are storing), if exists append the token to the request so this way each request should be fired with token if exists.

[Example](https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-interceptors/) for HttpInterceptor..

Now, simply whenever you got the token simply set the token to the place(cookie or local-storage) as soon as you set the token HttpInterceptor start adding access token to the request fired comes next to it.... Happy coding :)